# How to center text & image in a div/container

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulty aligning texts , i want the texts on the left  side of the div & the image on the right also centered equal from the top . I have tried justify-content and text-align but they dont give the results i need , i'm using css grid also .

here is the code in question

```css
/*this is just the css grid stuff*/
.contain{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  repeat(9, minmax(120px, 1fr)) ;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-rows:  minmax(50px , auto);
  grid-template-areas: 

  "s content2 content2 content2  content2 content2 content2 content2 empty2";
}

/* Here is the code */
.contentc{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: content2;
}

.text3{
  margin:auto;
    color: black;
}

.para3{
     color: black;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class= "contentc">
     <img class="img-3" src="Use Any Image" >
     <h2 class="text3">Twitter Clone </h2>
     <p class="para3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ratione itaque cupiditate porro ipsam quod, fugit reprehenderit autem architecto aliquam harum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/rb8skjep/2/

Comment: yes your very close the only thing is i wanted the text to be halfway/ lowered to the half of the image  . i could use margin-top: 50% but i wanted a responsive way  .

Comment: Use position:absolute style on both, and than use left:0 for the text and right:0 for the img

Comment: wow prottay thx man thats exactly what i was looking for , cant believe it was that easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you to learn flex-box, it makes grid outdated.

here is working code for you. this works great on my machine.

Don't forget you can nest flexboxes too which is how i made this work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            .contentc {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row-reverse;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: center;
            }

            #text {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: center;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contain">
            <div class="contentc">
                <img class="img-3" src="http://interactive.nydailynews.com/2016/05/simpsons-quiz/img/simp1.jpg" >
                <div id="text">
                    <h2 class="text3">Twitter Clone </h2>
                    <p class="para3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ratione itaque cupiditate porro ipsam quod, fugit reprehenderit autem architecto aliquam harum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow thank u so much dude this is exactly what i was looking for , i thought css grid was great guess i gotta start learning flexbox :)

Comment: haha, i know because i've been in the same situation. no problem man. i had a good cheat sheet, but i cant seem to find it, just google search for "flexbox cheatsheet" here is one https://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html the visuals let you understand what the commands do. this will work for almost everything u need to do with CSS

Answer (score 0):

sorry if my answer isn't that helpful but I hope it can in someway.

What I propose is you try to think more simple for the CSS as if all you want is for the text and images to be in certain positions then this code might be up your alley:

```
.para3 {display:inline; text-align: top}
.img-3 {float: right}
```

Hope it can contribute somewhat to helping you solve this problem.

Comment: thx for the help even though it wasn't quite what i was looking for i still appreciate the help :)